# How to capture link of a trello card after creating it from addCard trello API?

Tags: javascript, api, trello

I am creating a new card in trello board from JS function

```
var currentLocation = window.location.href;

function AddCardToTrello() {
  Trello.addCard({
  url: currentLocation,
  name: "{{ soproduct.product }}",
  due: {{ soproduct.required_date|date:"SHORT_DATE_FORMAT"  }}
});
}
```

After the creation, I am getting a Trello wizard that displays me with the link to the newly created card  on Trello board. I wand to capture this link and save it on my backed . How can I do it ? Is it possible to capture the data from same API call?

Comment: Are you using an npm package as intermediary? Something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/trello? Not suggesting you should, but the code is different from the example in the API docs.

Comment: Nope , I am not. It is pure django as backend and JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested this on the Trello Sandbox:

```
var destinationList = "XX_YOUR_LIST_ID_XX";

var success = function(successMsg) {
  asyncOutput(successMsg);
};

var error = function(errorMsg) {
  asyncOutput(errorMsg);
};

var newCard = 
  {name: "I just created a new card!", 
  desc: "Using the Trello API is fun and easy!",
  pos: "top", 
  due: null,
  idList: destinationList
  };

Trello.post('/cards/', newCard, success, error);
```

The `successMsg` callback value contains a param in the object:

`"url": "https://trello.com/c/PCJcEkmm/6-i-just-created-a-new-card"`

So my suggestion would be to add the process to save to backend, to your success function - depending on your plugin/script architecture used.

```
var success = function(successMsg) {
  console.log(successMsg);
  //Save to storage here
};

var error = function(errorMsg) {
  console.log(errorMsg);
};

function AddCardToTrello() {
  Trello.addCard({
  url: currentLocation,
  name: "{{ soproduct.product }}",
  due: {{ soproduct.required_date|date:"SHORT_DATE_FORMAT"  }}
}, success, error);
}
```

Comment: Thank you , 
this is what I am looking for . However when I try to debug I dont see anything in my console . It assumes I can not read from there as well.